Dygraph trying to change 2D y-axis limits
I am having trouble simply changing the y-axis minimum limit from the previous developers’ callback.  Y-axis maximum limit seems to work OK.
$("#simpleGraphs,#detailedGraphs").on('change', '.yRange', function (event) {
    var viewindex = event.target.id.split("-")[2];
    // This works for this part
    views[viewindex].dygraph.updateOptions({
        valueRange: [$("#y-min-" + viewindex).val(), $("#y-max-" + viewindex).val()],
    }, false);
    let currentValueRange = views[viewindex].dygraph.getOption('valueRange');
   
    // Min does not work and thus the y-axis limit is not changed
    // Previous developers’ comments
    // update y range selectors to match the new zoom level  The dygraph may actually adjust what we passed in - based on pixels or to make sure all the points are included
    // so need to ask it what it actually set, not just what we passed.
    let y_min = views[viewindex].dygraph.yAxisRange(0)[0];
    let y_max = views[viewindex].dygraph.yAxisRange(0)[1];
    y_min = currentValueRange[0];
    y_max = currentValueRange[1];

    // this works to reset the UX controls
    $("#y-min-" + viewindex).val(y_min);
    $("#y-max-" + viewindex).val(y_max);
});

I have tried about 20 ideas - the y-axis min limit did not change.
Here are sum of them:
// Tried setting the following value directly:
views[viewindex].dygraph.yAxisRange(0)[0] = 888;

// Tried reset to automatic range, then reset to my new range
views[viewindex].dygraph.updateOptions({ valueRange: null }, false);
views[viewindex].dygraph.updateOptions({
  valueRange: [$("#y-min-" + viewindex).val(), $("#y-max-" + viewindex).val()],}, false);

// force update
views[viewindex].dygraph.updateOptions({
  valueRange: [$("#y-min-" + viewindex).val(), $("#y-max-" + viewindex).val()], }, true); 


If you mention what 20 ideas you've tried that might help people answering narrow down a solution

What does $("#y-min-" + viewindex).val() evaluate to? The updateOptions approach is correct, modifying the return value of yAxisRange() won't do anything.
